# Rails: Server Monitoring - Ruby Running 17 processes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, webserver, monitoring, newrelic

I am monitoring my server on New Relic and the memory consumption of my app is rather high about 1 GB. Currently I am the only visitor to the site. When I drill down, I see that most of the consumption is because of Ruby. It says 17 instances running. What does this mean and how can I lower it?

Comment: What kind of server do you use. Uniorn, Passenger etc.?

Comment: Unicorn with Nginx. I have 4 workers set in Unicorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicorn is configured to run X number of instances by default. You can explicitly configure this number in `config/unicorn.rb` using `worker_processes 4` (to run 4 instances). Each unicorn instance will load up the entire stack for your application and keep it memory. A mid-sized rails applications tends to be around ~100 MB and up, it should stay at that level given there aren't any memory leaks. The memory consumption is generally affected by the number of dependencies and the complexity of the application.

Comment: I already have `worker_processes 4` in `config/unicorn.rb`. Despite this it says 17 processes running.

Comment: I'd suggest restarting the application if possible and check your logs for the number of instances getting started. If New Relic is reporting total memory consumption, the number seems ok.

Comment: Restarted. Back to 17 again. I guess there are 17 processes then. Gotta live with it.